# javascript show more datas on page scroll

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to show 4 items per page in each scroll. right now I am initially showing 4 items but when the page is scrolled I am showing all of the rest of the items. how can I achieve only 4 items per scroll? I tried using slice but couldn't execute the concept. I am using angular and ngx infinite scroll package.

component

```
import {
  Component, OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import { APIService } from 'src/app/services/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-categories',
  templateUrl: './categories.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./categories.component.css']
})

export class CategoriesComponent implements OnInit {
  isBottom = false
  names = []
  allProducts = []
  categories: any = []
  constructor(
    private apiService: APIService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getProductsData()
  }
  
  getProductsData() {
    this.apiService.GetProductData()
      .subscribe((response: any) => {
        response.forEach((product: any, index: number) => {
          if(index < 4) this.categories.push(product)
        })
        this.names = response.map((product: any) => product.title)
      },
        err => console.log(err))
  }

  onScroll() {
    console.log('SCROLLED') 
    this.apiService.GetProductData()
    .subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.categories = response
     this.isBottom = true
     console.log(this.categories)
    },
      err => console.log(err))
  }
}
```

template

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row min-vh-100">
        <div class="col-12">
            <header class="row">
                <app-top-nav></app-top-nav>

                <app-header [inputData]="names"></app-header>

            </header>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12">
            <main class="row">

                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 py-3">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12 text-center text-uppercase">
                                    <h2>Computers</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div *ngFor="let cat of categories" class="item" style="width:300px; float:left;">
                                    <div>
                                        <div>
                                            <div>
                                                <a href="product.html">
                                                    <img src="{{cat.image}}" alt="x" class="img-fluid">
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-12 mb-3">
                                                <a href="product.html" class="product-name">{{cat.title}}</a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-12 mb-3">
                                                <span class="product-price-old">

                                                </span>
                                                <br>
                                                <span class="product-price">

                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-12 mb-3 align-self-end">
                                                <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="button"><i
                                                        class="fas fa-cart-plus me-2"></i>Add to cart</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <br />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </main>
        </div>
        <h4 *ngIf="isBottom" style="text-align: center; color: black;">That's it. thanks for reading</h4>
        <div class="col-12 align-self-end">
            <app-footer></app-footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="search-results" infiniteScroll [infiniteScrollDistance]="2"
[infiniteScrollThrottle]="50" (scrolled)="onScroll()"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would edit your code as following. You need to add `page` variable, and pass to backend both `page` and `perPage` values. So each time you scroll down to the end, onScroll function is adding +1 to page variable and loading next 4 products. You need also edit backend endpoint to support this functionality.

```
import {
  Component, OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import { APIService } from 'src/app/services/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-categories',
  templateUrl: './categories.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./categories.component.css']
})

export class CategoriesComponent implements OnInit {
  isBottom = false
  names = []
  page = 1,
  allProducts = []
  categories: any = []
  constructor(
    private apiService: APIService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getProductsData()
  }
  
  getProductsData() {
    this.apiService.GetProductData({page: this.page, per_page: 4})
      .subscribe((response: any) => {
        response.forEach((product: any, index: number) => {
          this.categories.push(product)
        })
        this.names = response.map((product: any) => product.title)
      },
      err => console.log(err))
  }

  onScroll() {
    this.page++;
    this.apiService.GetProductData({page: this.page, perPage: 4})
    .subscribe((response: any) => {
      response.forEach((product: any) => this.categories.push(product));
     this.isBottom = true
    },
      err => console.log(err))
  }
}
```

**If you want to manage this on frontend**

I will suggest it only if you have small amount of products, say not more than 100. You can get all products at first time, and then slice in template.

```
import {
  Component, OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import { APIService } from 'src/app/services/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-categories',
  templateUrl: './categories.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./categories.component.css']
})

export class CategoriesComponent implements OnInit {
  isBottom = false
  names = []
  page = 1,
  allProducts = []
  categories: any = []
  constructor(
    private apiService: APIService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getProductsData()
  }

  getProductsData() {
    this.apiService.GetProductData()
      .subscribe((response: any) => {
        response.forEach((product: any, index: number) => {
          this.categories.push(product)
        })
        this.names = response.map((product: any) => product.title)
      },
      err => console.log(err))
  }

  onScroll() {
    this.page++;
  }
```

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row min-vh-100">
        <div class="col-12">
            <header class="row">
                <app-top-nav></app-top-nav>

                <app-header [inputData]="names"></app-header>

            </header>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12">
            <main class="row">

                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 py-3">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12 text-center text-uppercase">
                                    <h2>Computers</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div *ngFor="let cat of categories.slice(page * 4 - 4, page * 4)" class="item" style="width:300px; float:left;">
                                    <div>
                                        <div>
                                            <div>
                                                <a href="product.html">
                                                    <img src="{{cat.image}}" alt="x" class="img-fluid">
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-12 mb-3">
                                                <a href="product.html" class="product-name">{{cat.title}}</a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-12 mb-3">
                                                <span class="product-price-old">

                                                </span>
                                                <br>
                                                <span class="product-price">

                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-12 mb-3 align-self-end">
                                                <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="button"><i
                                                        class="fas fa-cart-plus me-2"></i>Add to cart</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <br />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </main>
        </div>
        <h4 *ngIf="isBottom" style="text-align: center; color: black;">That's it. thanks for reading</h4>
        <div class="col-12 align-self-end">
            <app-footer></app-footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="search-results" infiniteScroll [infiniteScrollDistance]="2"
[infiniteScrollThrottle]="50" (scrolled)="onScroll()"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, by the look of it your code should have worked but every time I scroll I lose the first 4 and don't get any more items and my page is empty

Comment: @AR, which one are you using frontend or backend pagination?

Comment: frontend, I dont have BE.

Comment: I think the end value should not be 4. that means it will end the extraction in the 4th position of the array, right?

Comment: @AR, yes, you are right

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked (from your edit)